# Getting InaccessibleObjectException when using app dynamics agent

Tags: java, ehcache, java-module, appdynamics

My application is currently using Java 8 and we are using docker image which runs on jre 8.
Due to some compliance reason we need to immediately upgrade docker image which runs on jre 11.
But our code will still be in Java 8, because of huge change required to covert in Jdk11 and time constraint.

We are also using app dynamics in our application. So with new docker image (JRE - 11) and with Jdk 8 code We are getting below error when application is starting up.

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field final com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.kernel.bootimpl.FastMethodInterceptorDelegatorImpl com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.kernel.bootimpl.FastMethodInterceptorDelegatorImpl$1.this$0 accessible: module com.appdynamics.appagent does not "opens com.singularity.ee.agent.appagent.kernel.bootimpl" to unnamed module @7a4264e1
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:340)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:280)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:176)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:170)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.ObjectGraphWalker.getAllFields(ObjectGraphWalker.java:271)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.ObjectGraphWalker.getFilteredFields(ObjectGraphWalker.java:229)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.ObjectGraphWalker.walk(ObjectGraphWalker.java:160)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.sizeof.SizeOf.deepSizeOf(SizeOf.java:72)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.DefaultSizeOfEngine.sizeOf(DefaultSizeOfEngine.java:190)
    at net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.AbstractPoolAccessor.add(AbstractPoolAccessor.java:63)
    at net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore.put(MemoryStore.java:281)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.putInternal(Cache.java:1620)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1546)
    at net.sf.ehcache.Cache.put(Cache.java:1511)
```

Exception is there while reloading cache using Ehcache. Currently using ehcache version 2.10.3

Interesting thing is if we remove app dynamics dependency and related javaagent.jar then application comes up fine.

Could someone please help resolve the issue

Comment: Did you try making use of `--add-opens`? It could be a short-term but quick solution. In the meanwhile, you shall be keen to see the version of libraries supporting the Java version you are upgrading to.

Comment: Yes I did, didn't work